# Do long polling using js in adobe air without memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, air, comet

I am making adobe air desktop app. I need to figure out how to do a long polling ajax request, without causing adobe air memory leak.

Basically my function is like this (i'm using jquery)

```
var stream = function() {
    $.ajax({
         url:"http://my-chat-server/stream",
         success:function(data) {
              //add recent msg to dom
              add_msg(data);
              stream();
         }
    });
}
```

My current implementation would fill 10mb in an hour and it's bad. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: come on, hint, links, anyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it,

Use air.URLStream, described here (scroll to bottom, example are there):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLStream.html#readUTF%28%29

after implementing air.URLStream, my app memory usage does not increase!
Using jquery ajax call will cause adobe air to leak memory - badly.